# Cross browser gradient mask

Tags: css, animation, svg, gradient

I have a CSS3 animation where a background is vertically scrolling. I want the top of the background to gradually fade out. I have achieved this in Chrome using:

```
-webkit-mask-box-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, black);
```

Is there a cross browser way of achieving this? Maybe using an SVG mask? Or even a JavaScript solution to setting up this animation?

Please see example code below:

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(24, 49, 67, .95), rgba(24, 49, 67, .88)), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/96380/pexels-photo-96380.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
div:before {
  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3454522/shapes1.svg);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  animation: bgscroll 100s infinite linear;
  -webkit-mask-box-image: linear-gradient(transparent, black);
}
@keyframes bgscroll {
  100% {
    background-position: 0px -3000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cross-browser Mask:**

Yes, we can achieve cross-browser masking using SVG masks. For this, we would need to put both the background image (your shapes SVG) and the mask on the same SVG element like in the below snippet. This part of the answer works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera (all latest versions), IE11 and Edge. It should also work in IE9 and IE10 because they have support for basic SVG, masking and clipping.

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(24, 49, 67, .95), rgba(24, 49, 67, .88)), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/96380/pexels-photo-96380.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 500 500' id='svg1'>
    <defs>
      <pattern id='bg-img' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' width='500' height='500' patternTransform='translate(0 3000)'>
        <image xlink:href='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3454522/shapes1.svg' x='0' y='0' width='500' height='500' />
      </pattern>
      <linearGradient id='grad' gradientTransform='rotate(90 250 250)'>
        <stop offset='0%' stop-color='black' />
        <stop offset='100%' stop-color='white' />
      </linearGradient>
      <mask id='msk'>
        <polygon points='0,0 0,500 500,500 500,0' fill='url(#grad)' />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <polygon points='0,0 0,500 500,500 500,0' fill='url(#bg-img)' mask='url(#msk)' />
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

**Cross-browser Mask Animation:**

In theory, the animation can also be achieved using SVG's `patternTransform` attribute. We can add a `translate` transform to the `pattern` element and make it mimic `background-position` animation.

```js
var y = 3000;
var svg1 = document.getElementById('bg-img');
setInterval(function() {
  y = (y <= 0) ? 3000 : y - 10;
  svg1.setAttribute('patternTransform', 'translate(0 ' + y + ')');
}, 100);
```

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(24, 49, 67, .95), rgba(24, 49, 67, .88)), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/96380/pexels-photo-96380.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 500 500' id='svg1'>
    <defs>
      <pattern id='bg-img' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' width='500' height='500' patternTransform='translate(0 3000)'>
        <image xlink:href='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3454522/shapes1.svg' x='0' y='0' width='500' height='500' />
      </pattern>
      <linearGradient id='grad' gradientTransform='rotate(90 250 250)'>
        <stop offset='0%' stop-color='black' />
        <stop offset='100%' stop-color='white' />
      </linearGradient>
      <mask id='msk'>
        <polygon points='0,0 0,500 500,500 500,0' fill='url(#grad)' />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <polygon points='0,0 0,500 500,500 500,0' fill='url(#bg-img)' mask='url(#msk)' />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this seems to work only in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. As usual, IE behaves differently and doesn't change the pattern position even though the `patterTransform` is getting applied correctly.

---

It ***works in IE also*** if we animate the `y` attribute of the pattern ***using snap.svg library***.

```js
var s = Snap("#svg1");

var polygon = s.polygon([0, 0, 0, 500, 500, 500, 500, 0]);
var mask = s.polygon([0, 0, 0, 500, 500, 500, 500, 0]);
var grad = s.gradient('L(0,0,500,500)#000-#fff').attr({
  gradientTransform: 'rotate(45,250,250)'
});
var pattern = s.image('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3454522/shapes1.svg', 0, 0, 500, 500)
  .pattern(0, 0, 500, 500);
mask.attr({
  fill: grad
});
polygon.attr({
  fill: pattern,
  mask: mask
});

function animIn() {
  this.animate({
    y: '0'
  }, 10000, mina.linear, animOut);
}

function animOut() {
  this.animate({
    y: '3000'
  }, 0, mina.linear, animIn);
};
pattern.animate({
  y: '3000'
}, 0, mina.linear, animIn);
```

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(24, 49, 67, .95), rgba(24, 49, 67, .88)), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/96380/pexels-photo-96380.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 500 500' id='svg1'>
  </svg>
</div>
```

(*A big thanks to [web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki) for helping me figure out the option using snap.svg.*)

Comment: Thanks, so much amazingly useful answer :)